# Generador de palabras aleatorias con final

Tags: javascript, php

estoy trabajando en un generador de palabras aleatorias, he hecho que cada vez que pulse un boton aparezca una palabra:

```
    <?php
     $frases = array(
     1 => "Una lavadora",
     2 => "Un movil",
     3 => "Una muñeca",
     );

     $numero = rand (1,3);

     echo "$frases[$numero]";
      ?>
      <input type="button" value="iniciar" onclick="document.location.reload();">
```

1-Cómo puedo hacer para que a la tercera vez que pulse el botón aparezca la palabra HAS PULSADO TRES VECES EL BOTÓN! y  deje de generar palabras?

2-¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo sin recargar la pagina entera?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agregando solo un contador y pidiendo la palabra por AJAX.

**PHP**

```
$frases = array(
  1 => "Una lavadora",
  2 => "Un movil",
  3 => "Una muñeca",
);

$numero = rand (1,3);

echo $frases[$numero];
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="word">
  <span id="wordOutput></span>
</div>
<button id="randomWordGen">Generate</button>
```

**JS**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var clickTimes = 0;
  var btnRandomWord = document.getElementById('randomWordGen');
  var wordOutput = document.getElementById('wordOutput');

  btnRandomWord.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (clickTimes < 3) {
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      // método HTTP y URL
      request.open('GET', '/randomwordgen.php');
      request.onload = function () {
        // estado 4 = petición completada y respuesta recibida
        if (request.readyState === 4) {
          // código HTTP 200 = petición exitosa
          if (request.status === 200) {
            wordOutput.textContent = request.responseText;
            clickTimes++;
          }
        }
      };
      request.send(); // se envía la petición
    } else {
      wordOutput.textContent = 'Has superado el límite palabras';
    }
  });
});
```

Lo anterior funcionará solo mientras no se recargue el documento, en caso se recargue, volverá a tener sus tres palabras. En caso desees que sea mientras el usuario tenga sesión, puedes usar en lugar del contador una cookie o mejor aún [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).

Comment: En programación decir "no me funciona" es igual a no decir nada. Mira la consola, ¿ves errores tanto en servidor y cliente?

Comment: En el editor de codigo me aparecen estos dos errores en el .js : 1 Expected an identifier and instead saw 'let' let clickTimes =0; 1 Stopping (4% scanned). let clickTimes = 0; No sé cual puede ser el error. En la consola me aparece el siguiente error: generador.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at generador.js:5

Comment: Supongo estás usando ES5. En ese caso reemplaza `let` por `var`. El otro error te indica que `btnRandomWord` es null por lo que **no existe `<button id="randomWordGen">Generate</button>`** en tu HTML. No copies y pegues el código que te expongo aquí, reeplaza el HTML si lo deseas por el que tengas tú, solo **ten en cuenta los `id`** que usas tanto en el HTML como en el JavaScript.

Comment: Me dice que no funciona el evento addEventListener (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at generador.js:5) ... Me estoy volviendo loco... ¿sabes porqué no funciona?

Comment: ¿Agregaste el HTML que te puse?

Comment: Sí reemplacé los let por var. Lo btnRandomWord, ¿por qué lo tengo que cambiar? no te entendí bien, no logro entender como dice que no exite el button, si en realidad si existe

Comment: A ver coleguita. JavaScript interactúa con tu código HTML. En el ejemplo que te puse, tengo un `button` y un `span`. Estas etiquetas tienen un ID, las cuales las uso para obtenerlas mediante JavaScript, por medio de `document.getElementById`. Esta función me devuelve el elemento en e HTML que tenga cierto ID; en caso no la encuentre **devuelve null**, osea, sin ninguna referencia. Una vez que tengo esos elementos, añado un listener al botón por medio de `addEventListener`. Pero, si tratas de usar un valor `null` como en cualquier lenguaje, obtendrás un error que es lo que te está pasando.

Comment: Entonces, ¿qué está pasando? Está pasando que **no se encuentra el** `button` **con el id** `btnRandomWord`, en pocas palabras, no existe en el HTML.

Comment: He actualizado el código JavaScript de mi respuesta. Reemplaza por el anterior y prueba nuevamente.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias @ruzgarcia , siento ser tan lento, pero se me da fatal el js( no hace falta que te lo diga). Ahora como hago para que coja las palabras del documento php? he visto que con   request.open('GET', '/randomwordgen.php'); supongo que deberia acceder a ellas y mostrarlas, pero no las muestra ¿como hago para mostrarlas?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53034/discussion-between-guzgarcia-and-antonio-angel-estrada-perez).

Answer (score 1):

Otra forma de hacerlo:

**PHP**

```
<?php
// definimos un array de valores en php
$arrayPHP = array(
 0 =>"Una lavadora",
 1 => "Un movil",
 2 => "Una muñeca",
 );
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="demo">Palabra!</p>
    <input type="button" value="iniciar" onclick="print()"> 
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// obtenemos el array de valores mediante la conversion a json del
// array de php
var arrayJS=<?php echo json_encode($arrayPHP);?>;

// Establecemos el valor minimo y maximo del array.
var max = <?= count($arrayPHP)-1 ?>;
var min = 0;
//Contador para controlar las pulsaciones del usuario.
var contador = 1;

function print() {
    var ind= randomIntFromInterval(min,max);
        if(contador <= 3) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arrayJS[ind];
            contador++;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Ha llegado al maximo";
        }
}
//Genera numeros aleatorios entre un rango dado por parametro.
function randomIntFromInterval(min,max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}
```

Convertimos un objeto PHP a JavaScript mediante `var arrayJS=<?php echo json_encode($arrayPHP);?>;`.

He tenido un problema al convertir el objeto y es que el indice del array en php debe comenzar en 0.